# Change of double integral order

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$$

Can we freely change the order of double indefinite integrals? Could you provide proof?

Comment: You'll want to look at [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: No problem! :-)